# Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent": connection.js

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, ajax, ajax-toolkit

Don't know why i am getting **unsafe header error** in console. Everything is working fine but i am wondering what is the error here. Below is the code:

```
function getFieldOptions (objName, ctrlFieldName) {
        // Isolate the Describe info for the relevant fields
        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 

        var objDesc = sforce.connection.describeSObject(objName);
        var ctrlFieldDesc, depFieldDesc;
        var dependentOptions =[];
        for (var i=0; i<objDesc.fields.length; i++) {
            var f = objDesc.fields[i];
            if (f.name == ctrlFieldName) {
                for (var i=0; i<f.picklistValues.length; i++) {
                    dependentOptions.push(f.picklistValues[i].label);
                }
            } 
        }
        console.log(dependentOptions);
        return dependentOptions;
    }
var choices = getFieldOptions('Task','Status');
```

This is the error i am getting in console.[image]

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue with Salesforce regarding this: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008eUCAAY
It also seems that this was an issue some years ago as well: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1LRAA0

Comment: @DerekF The second link was a bug in Chrome, not this error. And the error itself is harmless, and doesn't cause any bad behavior. While salesforce can certainly fix it, it won't fix scripts that are misbehaving. This error is nothing more than a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

The [XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method) specifically states that User-Agent must not be set by a client script, and any attempt to set that header should be ignored. The connection.js script tries to set "User-Agent" to "SFAJAX 1.0", and Chrome rejects this setting and outputs an error (as should all modern browsers). It does not cause the script to stop running; this error is completely harmless, and you can ignore it.

Historically, this was written in so that the Salesforce servers could identify that this was a salesforce AJAX Toolkit API call. This toolkit predates the requirement that some headers be rejected if a script tries to set them, and most, if not all, browsers happily allowed you to spoof the User-Agent string. These days, the header is effectively ignored, but it's still in the source code. In fact, you can see there's still even support for Msxml2.XMLHTTP and Microsoft.XMLHTTP, despite the fact that the browsers that use those objects are no longer in the Supported Browser list.

If you're having a problem with the AJAX Toolkit not doing what you expect, this error is not the cause of your problems.

Comment: I am developing a salesforce app and curious to know before giving it to checkmarx if it fails due to this error.  Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: @HeadInCloud I don't think checkmarx checks for benign script errors. It's primary focus is security problems, major optimizations, and unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The spec changed in August 2015. It is now permitted to set User-Agent in setRequestHeader but mozilla are the only organisation to actually implement this so far. 
The other browsers need to catch up!